# With tinymce, the formatting seems to change when I copy content from a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce, rte

If I copy + paste from a word doc, it's fine, and it produces near enough an exact copy.

If I display the content in a  within an iframe (to prevent css interfering) it appears exactly as it did in the editor.

If I then do this:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceReplaceContent",false, $("#frameBody").contents().find("#txtBody").html());
```

it copies it into the tinyMCE window, but the formatting is a bit different. Bullet points are hollow circles instead of regular circles, and there is a fair bit of extra spacing.

Any idea how I can fix this?

I'm creating my tinyMCE like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,searchreplace,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",
});

<textarea name='FishBody' style='width:919px; height:600px' id='txtFishBody'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it, it turns out it was an issue with the way that the html was being pulled.

Essentially, when you save this html:

```
<div>
Hello
</div>
```

you end up with

```
<div>\r\nHello\r\n<div>
```

I was countering that by replacing \r\n with `<br/>` but it seems that's not necessary - the extra `<br>` tags were confusing it. I changed it to replace `\r\n` with empty string, and all problems are solved :)

Answer (score 1):

The tinymce editor like most rte uses a standard css for its editor iframe. That is the reason why bullets look different. Another reason for a different look might be that the cleanup function removes invalid html elements and attributes (you might want to have a closer look into the tinymce configuration settings [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children)).

Comment: I thought it could be CSS but I dunno, if I click a hollow bullet point, and uncheck the bullet point option on the toolbar, it reverts to text. If I then click it again, it goes back to being a bullet point, but this time it's a solid one!

Comment: There are many issue to get word context to display as desired in rte editors. Can you show me the editor content before and after you switched the bullet option?

Comment: Aha, before, it's `<ul><ul><li>....` and after, it is just `<ul><li>...` so that explains why it's hollow, it's nested. But I have no idea why - the source markup is a plain textarea with no CSS in an iframe, and the source is `<ul><li>...</li></ul>`.

What I'm doing is typing stuff into the editor, saving it, loading it back into a <div> and then when I press a button, it invokes the copy operation to put it back into the editor. I'm literally trying to feed the output back into the editor, although it's going via a database first.

Comment: but tinymce and other editors use a standard css (which can be found in the head of the editors iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option

**paste_retain_style_properties: all**  --OR "color font-size" whatever you want to include

example: Copy pasting my code which has other options, in case it helps

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            width: "100%",
            height : "250",
            encoding: "xml",
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            color_cols: "5",
            setup: function (ed) {
                ed.on('init', function () {
                    this.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = '10pt';
                    this.getDoc().body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
                });
            },
            theme: "modern",
            browser_spellcheck: true,
            plugins:
            [
                "table paste textcolor"
            ],
            paste_retain_style_properties: "all",
            toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontsizeselect fontselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
            toolbar2: "copy cut paste | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor | searchreplace | table"
        });
```

Refer : https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/